# Probability problem (University course)

Tags: probability

In a university, $30$% of the students major in Business Management, $25$% major in mathematics, and $10$% major in both Business Management and Mathematics. A student from this university is selected at random. If the student majors in Business Management, what is the probability that he/she also majors in Mathematics? I've come up with the solution of by adding them both
 $.30$+$.25$ and then multiply $.10$. Am I missing something or did I come up with the wrong solution?

Comment: I suggest drawing up a Venn diagram and reason using that. That should help intuition.

Comment: For intuition:  Say there are exactly $100$ students.  Of these, we must have $10$ who major in both, $20$ who major in Business only, $15$ that major in Math only and $55$ who do neither.  Does that clarify matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are actually looking for the probability that someone majors in *both* courses over the probability that someone majors in Buisness. This is obviously $\frac{1}{3}=33%.$ The reason your answer is incorrect is because the total probability of someone majoring in math is irrelevant; the people majoring in Math but not Buisness Management are not our concern.

(In general you can use $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A and B)}{P(B)}$. We're looking for P(Math|Buisness))

Comment: should it be 1/4 ? since (0.25 * 0.30 )/0.30?

Comment: The events are not independent; you are told that 10% of students major in Business and Math.

Comment: thanks. I now understand the problem. Quick question though, what do you call this specific type of probability? Is it conditional?

Comment: Yes, it's conditional.